# Two dimensional array in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

I want to use two dimensional array in ios, for example I want to prepare an array for `tableview` datasource,

`UITableViewCell array[sections][rows];`

Something like this, and here I cant predeclare the size also.

Thanks

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4982636/845115)

Comment: A little advice... I would recommend you to not manually store your TableCells in arrays, since the cells can be reused by UITableView for better memory handling and performance, using the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier method. 

You should keep the representation of the data that you want to show in lists, arrays or whatever you like, and then bind the data to your cells in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 3];

[dataArray insertObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"0",@"0",@"0",nil] atIndex:0];
[dataArray insertObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"0",@"0",@"0",nil] atIndex:1];
[dataArray insertObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"0",@"0",@"0",nil] atIndex:2];
```

And this is how you select your value from array

```
NSMutableArray *subArray = [dataArray objectAtIndex:2];
NSLog(@"data : %@",[subArray objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

set up an `NSDictionary` and use an `NSIndexPath` as the key for each cell

Comment: Wouldn't that be very confusing if the list in the table view changed, i.e. if an item was removed from the list? Then you would need to change the keys for all following items in the list...

Comment: @jake_hetfield absolutely. it would only be useful for static datasources. but then storing cells in an array seems like a waste of effort to me anyway

Answer (score 1):

Syntactic sugar approach. Note that this approach will not automatically create a `NSMutableArray` of a given size. The initial array size will be 0, 0.

```
NSMutableArray *yourArray = [@[ [@[] mutableCopy]] mutableCopy];

// add an object to the end of your array
[yourArray[section][row] addObject:@(22)];

// set/change an NSNumber object at a particular location in the 2D array.
yourArray[section][row] = @(22);

// Retrieve a value, converting the NSNumber back to a NSInteger
NSInteger result = [yourArray[section][row] integerValue];
```

Comment: This is a good start, but showing how to expand it to show how to add items and how to access items would make it a more complete answer.

Comment: Added a bit more functionality @Caleb