# How do I create a multidimensional array?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I need to keep 90x90 array data for iphone app. how can i keep this data? making an multi-dimensional array is a solution for this big table. or is there an other solution.

Comment: What kind of interactions with the data will you need?

Comment: Check the accepted answer to this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4982617/objective-c-create-a-multi-dimensional-array-with-the-dimensions-specified-at

Comment: ok i got it.i will try. thanks a lot: Pez & Joe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the matrix is always 90x90, then you should just use C arrays.

Unless you have a special need for passing the matrix around, searching using predicates, or need some other feature of NSArray, then keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- Use a single Obj-C array containing 8100 elements and map your rows and columns onto the single index yourself: `index = (row * 90) + column;`
- Create an Obj-C array containing 90 Obj-C arrays of 90 elements each.
- Hash the row and column together into a single key that you can use with a dictionary. This could be a good solution especially if the array is sparse.
- Use a single- or multi-dimensional C array, especially if the elements of the array are plain old C types, like `int`. If you're storing objects, it's better to go with an Obj-C container.

Answer (score 0):

Iphone's have a built in database SQL-Lite. I'd look into that to see if it meets you needs

Comment: i will try array first. if it slows the app than i look sqlite. thanks Sunrize

Comment: @AykutE sqlite will slow your code down, not the other way around. Only consider SQLite if you find the array insufficient and you require persistent storage.