# in iOS 5 method returning an NSString returns garbage sometimes

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I have an app that works fine in iOS 4, but there is a crash when scrolling a UITableView when the same exact code is compiled using iOS5 and XCode 4.2.  The offending code is below:

```
    - (NSString *)getDefaultIconName {
        NSInteger value = [self.iconId characterAtIndex:0] % 4;
        NSString *returnValue = nil;

        switch (value) {
            case 0:
                returnValue = @"default_icon_1";
                break;
            case 1:          
                returnValue = @"default_icon_2";
                break;
            case 2:
                returnValue = @"default_icon_3";
                break;
            case 3:
            default:
                returnValue = @"default_icon_4";
                break;
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```

This method is called from within a subclass of UITableViewCell that is created or re-used in a call to cellForRowAtIndexPath.  When the table is created and the cells are shown, this call returns a correct string.  When I scroll down the table, this call returns an invalid reference, which causes my attempt to retain the string in another class to crash with EXEC_BAD_ACCESS.  In the debugger, I can see that the UITableViewCell exists correctly and all values are set properly except for the return value for this call, which says Invalid CFStringRef.

Oddly, if I place an NSLog statement printing out the returnValue before returning, it does not crash.  The same is true if I put a check to see if returnValue isKindOfClass:[NSString class] before returning it.

A third thing I noticed is that if I compile with code optimization turned off, it also does not crash.

I want to make sure i fix this correctly in the app so that the problem does not occur again in the future.

edit: Sorry, the returnValue missing a * was a typo.

Comment: Methods should not be prefixed with `get`;  it should just be `defaultIconName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing obviously wrong with the code as you've pasted it, so look for problems (memory corruption, over-released objects) elsewhere.

Also, rather than a switch() statement, you could index into an array of return values:

```
NSInteger value = [self.iconId characterAtIndex:0] % 4;
NSString *icons[4] = {@"default_icon_1",
   @"default_icon_2",
   @"default_icon_3",
   @"default_icon_4"};

return icons[value];
```

Comment: David, the code you provided actually does prevents the crashing.  However, using an if-else to replace the switch does not.  Also, just adding NSLog(returnValue); before returning also prevents the crash.  Do you have any idea why that might be, or why your fix works?

Comment: It's only "fixing" the problem by accident -- there's really nothing wrong with what you were doing in the first place. All the things you're seeing -- problem goes away when you turn off optimization, or when you add NSLog statements -- point to some kind of memory corruption problem (for example, continuing to use an object after you've release()d it).

Comment: I will see if I can reproduce this scenario in a small test environment and open a bug report with apple.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add a `*` to `returnValue` when you are declaring it.  Right now it's not a pointer.

Comment: Ah, yes, you should declare `returnValue` like this `NSString *returnValue = nil;` (unless this is simply a typo).

Comment: Oh, looks like someone already said this on the comment on the original question.

Comment: Sorry, the * was a typo when posting the question.

Comment: Then it sounds like it is definitely your optimization settings.  Try running the compiler with `-mno-thumbs` flag enabled, although i'm not entirely sure what it does specifically.  That's a solution for optimization-related crashes i've seen floating around twitter.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because in case 3 you are returning returnValue when it is nil? If so, set returnValue to your default value.

Also make sure you don't divide by zero.

Comment: `case 3` falls through to the `default` case.

Comment: The code definitely does not divide by 0, it's a mod 4 operation. 0 % 4 will return 0.  Also, case 3 does not have a break, so it is returning the default value, not nil.

Comment: doh! of course, I missed the absent break. only mentioned the divisible by zero as I recall upgrading a project to ios5 I had warnings about this (when I ran analyze) that I had to fix.

Answer (score -2):

`switch case` **does not** work with Objective-C objects. Use `if-else` instead.

Comment: NSInteger is not an NSObject. It is simply a typedef for an integer type. So no problem here.

Comment: Yes, `NSInteger` is simply a typecast int whose size depends on architecture.  `NSNumber` is an objective-c object.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445173/when-to-use-nsinteger-vs-int

Comment: My apologies - read this as 'switch case' does not work with Objective-C.

Comment: While what I say is correct, it is redundant in this case because of course NSInteger isn't an object. I stand corrected.

Comment: I actually tried using an if-else construct instead of the switch-case and the same problem occurred.  I think the problem has something to do with the way iOS 5 is optimizing the code on compile.