# cocoa lightweight string

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, boolean, nsinteger

`NSString`, `NSBool`, and `NSInteger` come with a lot of extra functionality that is nice when needed, but becomes baggage when unnecessary. Is there a lightweight way to hold on to strings like there is for bool and int?

- `NSBool` has `BOOL`
- `NSInteger` has `int`

What does `NSString` have?

Comment: NSBool has BOOL is a lie

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NSInteger` is just a raw C-type (just like `int` -- and, to be precise about it, [`NSInteger` is a `typedef` to either `long` or `int` depending on architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445173/when-to-use-nsinteger-vs-int)), and there is no such thing as `NSBool`.  You're probably thinking about `NSNumber` *objects*.

`NSString` objects, on the other hand, are really easy to hold onto and work with.  Yes, you can get the raw bytes and put them into a "`const char *`", but if you're working with Objective C, you'll find there are less headaches to leave strings as Objective C objects rather than C pointers.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `const char *`