# Implicit conversion loses integer precision

Tags: objective-c

can anyone help me 
i am setting um pushwoosh and i am getting this error

/PushNotificationManager.m:43:111: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') to 'int'

Comment: Post the source code, please

Comment: Use variables of type `NSInteger` to store integers instead of `int`s.

Answer (score 4):

`NSInteger` has a larger size (equals `long`)  on 64bit systems than `int`. The warning tells you, that you may loose information when transforming an `NSInteger`to `int`. You can suppress the warning by typecasting to `(int)`, but then you may suddenly find strange calculations due to the precision loss. Better to use `NSInteger`instead of `int` for all integer variables. See also [When to use NSInteger vs. int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445173/when-to-use-nsinteger-vs-int) for some more discussion.

Implicit vs. explicit:

```
NSInteger myLong = 11234;
int myInt = myLong; // implicit
int myInt2 = (int)myLong; // explicit by typecasting; you should know why you do this.
```

Comment: can anyone connect to my mac via teamviever i am not sure how to do this? my Skype is: elvarpall

Comment: you are not sure how you can change a variable from int to NSInteger? Just go to the line Xcode gives you the warning for. And if necessary, typecast.

Comment: PushNotificationManager.m is the file you are looking for. You can go to the location in file by clicking the warning in the warnings list in Xcode....

Comment: this is the line with the error    return [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"increment", @"operation", [NSNumber numberWithInt:delta], @"value", nil];
}

Comment: replace [NSNumber numberWithInt:delta] with [NSNumber numberWithInteger:delta]

Comment: thank from 22 to 14 errors it coms new errors when i did that

Comment: i really would like if someone can connect to my Mac and take a look at my Xcode app via team viewer my Skype is: elvarpall