# NSInteger integer initialisation

Tags: objective-c

Is there is no needs of declaring NSInteger using the alloc and initialise keyword? and why?

I was trying doing NSInteger *choice = [[NSInteger alloc] init]; while I found direct assignment

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use NSInteger vs int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445173/when-to-use-nsinteger-vs-int)

Answer (score 3):

NSInteger is just typedef of int or long (depends on platform)

So you can initialize something like that

```
NSInteger i = 10;
```

Quote from SDK documentation

NSInteger
Used to describe an integer.

```
typedef long NSInteger;
```

When building 32-bit applications, NSInteger is a 32-bit integer. A 64-bit application treats NSInteger as a 64-bit integer.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

NSInteger is not an Objective-C object.  It's a datatype (much like C's `int` or `char` types). You do not need to call "`alloc`" (to explicitly allocate memory space) for it.

You can read up on the other Objective-C data types (like `NSRange`, which you'll use a lot of once you get into NSString *objects*) [in this Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html).