# Is an NSUInteger equivalent to a plain old int?

Tags: objective-c

I'm just learning. In this tutorial, they've declared a block that takes `NSUInteger` arguments, and then they simply pass in `6` and `4` . . . I was under the impression all these `NS` things are object wrappers, different from the built-in c-types.

Now that I'm writing this, I remember them saying earlier that we didn't need the `*` in `NSUInteger` declarations because it *wasn't* like the other `NS` objects.

But...an `NSUInteger` is obviously not a c-type. So...what's going on here?

Comment: Go to Definition and you'll see where it came from.

Comment: NSUInteger *is* a plain old integer type, but it may not be identical to `unsigned int`.

Comment: As you are seeing, not everything that begins with `NS` is a class. Some are typedefs for primitive types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short Answer: Sometimes, NSUInteger is "unsigned int". But sometimes it is not. It depends the platform you compile your code.

Long Answer:

NSUInteger or NSInteger is defined in the NSObjCRuntime.h, you can Command+click on an NSUInteger and see the define below:

```
#if __LP64__ || (TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED && !TARGET_OS_IPHONE) || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

So, generally speaking, it means in a 64-bit environment, NSUInteger is an alias of unsigned long, while in a 32 bit environment, it is an int.

Because the new iPhone 5s is running on a 64-bit CPU, so it is recommended to use NSUInteger or NSInteger instead the plain unsign int or int.

And at last, NSUInteger is a real c-type indeed, in another name so the complier can do some work for you to handle it better.

Answer (score 1):

NSUInteger is like unsigned integer
NSInteger is like int

See

[When to use NSInteger vs. int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445173/when-to-use-nsinteger-vs-int)

Answer (score 1):

If, in XCode, you *option-Click* on NSInteger you'll go to the definition:

```
#if __LP64__ || TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED || TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_OS_WIN32 || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

So for 64-bit systems, it is defined as **long**, not as **int**.