# Benefits of using NSInteger over int?

Tags: ios, objective-c, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, nsinteger

I am trying to comprehend how development is affected when developing for both 32-bit and 64-bit architectures. From what I have researched thus far, I understand an `int` is always 4 bytes regardless of the architecture of the device running the app. But an `NSInteger` is 4 bytes on a 32-bit device and 8 bytes on a 64-bit device. I get the impression `NSInteger` is "safer" and recommended but I'm not sure what the reasoning is for that.

My question is, if you know the possible value you're using is never going to be large (maybe you're using it to index into an array of 200 items or store the count of objects in an array), why define it as an `NSInteger`? That's just going to take up 8 bytes when you won't use it all. Is it better to define it as an `int` in those cases? If so, in what case would you want to use an `NSInteger` (as opposed to `int` or `long` etc)? Obviously if you needed to utilize larger numbers, you could with the 64-bit architecture. But if you needed it to also work on 32-bit devices, would you not use `long long` because it's 8 bytes on 32-bit devices as well? I don't see why one would use `NSInteger`, at least when creating an app that runs on both architectures.

Also I cannot think of a method which takes in or returns a primitive type - `int`, and instead utilizes `NSInteger`, and am wondering if there is more to it than just the size of the values. For example, `(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`. I'd like to understand why this is the case. Assuming it's possible to have a table with 2,147,483,647 rows, what would occur on a 32-bit device when you add one more - does it wrap around to a -2,147,483,647? And on a 64-bit device it would be 2,147,483,648. (Why return a signed value? I'd think it should be unsigned since you can't have a negative number of rows.)

Ultimately, I'd like to obtain a better understanding of actual use of these number data types, perhaps some code examples would be great!

Comment: ["When to use NSInteger vs int?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4445173/1378447)

Comment: @Joey: Did you get a 'right' answer? I cannot find, in answers, that you asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally think that, 64-bit is actually the reason for existence for NSInteger and NSUInteger; before 10.5, those did not exist. The two are simply defined as longs in 64-bit, and as ints in 32-bit.

`NSInteger`/`NSUInteger` are defined as *dynamic `typedef`*s to one of these types, and they are defined like this:

```
#if __LP64__ || NS_BUILD_32_LIKE_64
typedef long NSInteger;
typedef unsigned long NSUInteger;
#else
typedef int NSInteger;
typedef unsigned int NSUInteger;
#endif
```

Thus, using them in place of the more basic C types when you want the 'bit-native' size.

I suggest you to throughly read this link.
[CocoaDev has some more info.](http://web.archive.org/web/20120206001941/http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSUInteger)

For proper format specifier you should use for each of these types, see the [String Programming Guide's section on Platform Dependencies](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW5)

Answer (score 2):

I remember when attending iOS developer conference. you have to take a look on the data-type in iOS7. for example, you use `NSInteger` in 64-bit device and save it on iCloud. then you want to sync to lower device (say iPad 2nd gen), your app will not behave the same, because it recognizes `NSInteger` in 4 bytes not 8 bytes, then your calculation would be wrong.

But so far, I use `NSInteger` because mostly my app doesn't use iCloud or doesn't sync. and to avoid compiler warning.

Comment: I think, it's a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apple uses int because for a loop control variable (which is only used to control the loop iterations) int datatype is fine, both in datatype size and in the values it can hold for your loop. No need for platform dependent datatype here. For a loop control variable even a 16-bit int will do most of the time.

Apple uses NSInteger for a function return value or for a function argument because in this case datatype [size] matters, because what you are doing with a function is communicating/passing data with other programs or with other pieces of code.

> Apple uses NSInteger (or NSUInteger) when passing a value as an
>   argument to a function or returning a value from a function.

The only thing I would use NSInteger for is passing values to and from an API that specifies it. Other than that it has no advantage over an int or a long. At least with an int or a long you know what format specifiers to use in a printf or similar statement.

Answer (score 1):

As a continue to Irfan's answer: 
    sizeof(NSInteger)
equals a processor word's size. It is much more simple and faster for processor to operate with words