# Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int' - Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

I've seen a few Q&A's here about the same error but none of them was helpful. I'm still getting the same error. What do I need to change? This is what I've got right now. 
The error is concerning this line: imageIndex = (imageIndex < 0) ? ([images count] -1):

Thanx for your help!

```
#import "Photogallery.h"

@interface Photogallery ()


@end

@implementation Photogallery
@synthesize imageView;
int imageIndex = 10;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


}
- (IBAction)handleSwipe:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {

NSArray *images=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1.jpg",@"2.jpg",@"3.jpg",@"4.jpg",@"5.jpg",@"6.jpg",@"7.jpg",@"8.jpg",@"9.jpg",@"10.jpg", nil];

UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection direction = [(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender direction];

switch (direction) {
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
        imageIndex++;
        break;
    case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
        imageIndex--;
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
imageIndex = (imageIndex < 0) ? ([images count] -1):
imageIndex % [images count];
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:imageIndex]];
}


@end
```

Comment: Is this objective-c ? (because not c++ for sure)

Comment: Sorry, wrong tag. It is objective-c in fact

Comment: Look at the docs for `NSArray count`. See its return value? Use the same data type for your `imageIndex` variable instead of `int`.

Comment: Maddy has the right answer.  Have you set all the warnings to errors, as this is usually just a compiler warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use NSInteger, not int, in Objective-C code.

Here is a really good explanation:

[When to use NSInteger vs. int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445173/when-to-use-nsinteger-vs-int)

Comment: Using NSInteger not int made the error go. Thanx a lot @KirkSpaziani