# Objective-C: @property attribute for basic types

Tags: objective-c, properties

The common practice before arc was to use assign for basic types like int.
What are we supposed to use for them when using ARC?

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) int foo;
```

Also: Why does Apple seem to encourage use of NSInteger instead of e.g. long?

Answer (score 2):

The following is enough since `assign` is the default anyway:

`@property (nonatomic) int foo;`

Regarding `NSInteger` vs `int` / `long`: `NSInteger` is preferred because it removes you having to worry about what bit-architecture you are on, als Leejay already mentioned.

I want to additionally mention that using `NSInteger` makes it a bit easier to transition to `swift` in the future, since `NSInteger` is simply bridged to `Int`, on of the most "native" data types. If you use `int` in Objective-C you have to deal with `Int32` in swift, same goes for `long` (`Int64`). Is simply gets messy and can be avoided pretty easily by using `NSInteger` for all properties and method parameters or return values.

Answer (score 1):

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) int foo;
```

is still used for primitives.

ARC stops you from using `retain`, like

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSObject *foo;
```

subbing it with `weak` or `strong`.

And you want to use `NSInteger` because it is a known number of bits no matter if you are running on 32- or 64-bit architecture. `int` or `long` can be architecture-dependent, so it just gives you extra predictability/piece of mind.

There's a [great discussion about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445173/when-to-use-nsinteger-vs-int) in a previous question.