# How could i write a function in Objective - C which gets 3 parameters and in the first parameter is stored the sum of the 2nd and 3rd parameter?

Tags: objective-c, function-parameter

I am new to Objective C programming and i would like to know the steps/approach of resolving this exercise.

Comment: Your question was down voted (by somebody else) because one of the rules for Stack Overflow is to not ask for book/tutorial/framework recommendations. I suggest you edit your question to focus on the problem and use google to search for resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)myValue:(int *) sum istheSumOfFirst:(int)a andSecond:(int)b {
    *sum = a + b;
}
```

And you can call the function like

```
int sum;
[self myValue:&sum istheSumOfFirst:5 andSecond:3];
NSLog(@"%i", sum);
```

Console:$ 8

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)addingSumInto:(NSInteger *)sum byAddingValue:(NSInteger)integerOne andValue:(NSInteger)integerTwo{

    //Here you can Do with these three parameters.
    //As your question is unclear so lets add above three and then simply return them


   *sum = integerOne + integerTwo;

}
```

Now in your main Method call above method like this..

```
NSInteger sum;
[self addingSumInto:&sum byAddingValue:99 andValue:155];
NSLog(@"%ld",sum);
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. So here it is : a function inside the main sends 3 arguments, so when this function is called it must have 3 parameters , right? In the 1st parameter will be stored the sum of the value of the 2nd and the 3rd parameter after which it will be printed by NSLog like NSLog(@"The sum of 2ndparam and 3rd parameter is: " , 1stparameter). I dont know how to solve this so i didnt write a format specifier in NSLog. 

I wanted the 1st parameter to be a pointer type.

Btw. why did you use NSInteger? Is this a must when working with numbers of type int?

Comment: Check this stack answer that why we use NSInteger instead of int.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445173/when-to-use-nsinteger-vs-int