# Why is there NSInteger and not NSLong or even NSLongLong?

Tags: objective-c, nsinteger

NSInteger is integer object. So surely there should be long object?

Comment: NSInteger is not an object. It is a primitive type

Comment: NSInteger is not an object? Ah yes, I got mixed up with NSNumber.

Comment: that's a common mistake

Comment: I wish they are named differently. Like CGInteger or something. NS normally is for objects.

Comment: @GeneCode The `NS` prefix is for everything that commonly comes from the Foundation and AppKit frameworks — including things like `NSRect`, `NSPoint`, and other C types and structs. `CG` is the prefix for the CoreGraphics framework, which is unrelated.

Comment: @ItaiFerber ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSInteger` and `NSUInteger` are platform specific, so on 32 bit system is declared as an int and on 64 bit system it is declared as a long.

Comment: So if 4billion is held by NSInteger, it works on 64bit and overflow on 32bit?

Comment: Yep, you can see in the `NSObjCRuntime.h` header file.

Comment: That sucks don't it? I don't see the point of using NSInteger.

Comment: Well it allows you code to be future proof, why use 32bit int on a 64 bit system. But if you know before hand that you need to store a large number you should a type that can hold it.

Comment: Yea. That's what I mean. We should always know beforehand the range of the number that we're gonna use.

Answer (score 1):

NSInteger is a foundation type, [as you can see here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/1613028-foundation_data_types).

There are also other useful primitive types, like NSRect, NSSize, etc.

Apple simply chose not to have a NSLong or NSLongLong type defined in foundation.

More information as to when to use NSInteger (and what the considerations are behind them) can be found [in this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445173/when-to-use-nsinteger-vs-int?rq=1).